# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mirage'

Tags: python, module

```
from mirage.fact import Dataconfig
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mirage'
```

[File Structure diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFMrA.png)

I am running the file called Base.py and i am `from mirage.fact import Datsconfig`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Assuming you've already installed [mirage](https://pypi.org/project/mirage/) with `pip install mirage` maybe this is a conflict with the global packages. Did you create a Virtual Environment and activated it before trying to run?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
from mirage.fact import Dataconfig
```

Comment: I tried that and it seemed to work for a while, but after I put my computer to sleep, the issue has come back.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an empty file `__init__.py` in the folder mirage and an empty file `__init__.py` in the folder mirage/fact.